# Microsoft browsers not posting form to iframe when action url is cross-origin

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, cors, microsoft-edge

I have a web site that exports reports to various file formats by posting a form with a target in an iframe, and the http response is a file that downloads.

In the past, my web server and html/js assets were all hosted together in same domain, and all the browsers worked fine.

I just moved my static assets to a cdn on a different domain, and allow that domain on my web site using `access-control-allow-origin`, `x-frame-options allow-from`, and `content-security-policy frame-ancestors`. The report exporting works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but no longer works on either Microsoft Edge or IE browsers.

On Edge, the developer tools network trace shows that the `POST` to the server is "Pending" and never completes, yet there is no server log of the request. On IE, the `HTTP POST` does complete fine, but the browser doesn't prompt to save the file. On both browsers, the developer tools show that there is no `Origin` HTTP header, which is crucial for setting the`x-frame-options` response. So that might explain why IE refused to save the file. But Edge doesn't even submit the request.

My questions are:

1. Why won't edge submit the HTTP `POST`?
2. Why does neither browser send the HTTP `Origin` header? Am I supposed to rely on the`Referer` header?

Comment: the f12 console tab should list and XSS and security errors. In IE first select Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. The File>Properties menu will tell you which IE security zone the host maps to... Edge does not use security zones, but its f12>Console should show you any security or xss errors.

Comment: Thanks @RobParsons. Please see my answer below which seems to be the more reliable approach.

Comment: thanks for the fb. Glad to hear you found a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming to the conclusion that the approach of posting a form to an iframe in order to download a file is outdated and likely to be less than fully supported by browsers, particular in cors scenario. Instead, I think using the html5 files api may be the more modern approach, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797348/1237919

Indeed, I tried that approach and it works great in all browsers!